# Marginal distribution from conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let a random variable X be normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and let the conditional distribution of Y given X be normal $N(a_1+a_2X,\sigma_1^2)$. Find the marginal distribution of Y.

I found their joint density by multiplying the conditional density of Y given X and the density of X. But I couldn't integrate it wrt x to get marginal density of Y. Then I realized that $Y|X-a_1-a_2X$ is $N(0,\sigma_1^2)$, but I couldn't proceed after that.

Comment: Hint: Since $X=\mu+\sigma U$ with $U$ standard normal, $Y=a_1+a_2\mu+a_2\sigma U+\sigma_1V$ with $V$ standard normal independent of $U$. What is the distribution of $a_2\sigma U+\sigma_1V$?

Comment: Got it! Thanks!